# PyQt5 layout.addWidget will not accept pyqtgraph widget

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to add a GraphicsLayoutWidget from pyqtgraph to a PyQt application. On multiple machines, the code below works without error: I see a QLineEdit input textbox above a black square.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication
import sys

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, headers: list = None, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('QLineEdit'))
        w = QLineEdit()
        print(type(w))
        layout.addWidget(w)

        x = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        print(type(x))
        layout.addWidget(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Test()
    main.show()
    app.exec()
```

However, on one machine, I receive the error below and the code will not run.

```
File "my_file.py", line 22, in __init__
    layout.addWidget(self, w)
TypeError: addWidget(self, a0: QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'GraphicsLayoutWidget'
```

I've tried adding a self.setLayout(layout), but this doesn't fix the issue.

I updated both machines so that their installed packages and versions both match. On the non-working machine, I tried uninstalling pyqtgraph and PyQt5, then reinstalling them with PyQt5 first followed by pyqtgraph. The error persists.

On both machines I am running:

- Python 3.11.1
- PyQt5 5.15.8
- pyqtgraph 0.13.1

All other packages that I see listed by pip freeze or pip list are identical in version, i.e. the lists contain the same packages and the same versions of each package.

The print lines in the above code print the class of each object.

For QLineEdit: <class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit'>.
For GraphicsLayoutWidget: <class 'pyqtgraph.widgets.GraphicsLayoutWidget.GraphicsLayoutWidget'>.

I've run the code in PyCharm as well as from the command line and the result is the same. For some reason, it seems that PyQt5 is not identifying widgets from pyqtgraph.widgets as QWidget.

I don't even know how to reproduce the error on the working machines.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: First import PyQt, then import pyqtgraph.

Comment: Wow, this solved the problem! THANK YOU! Why did the import order matter, especially specifically on machine but not others?

Comment: You probably have PySide or *another* PyQt major version installed. When pyqtgraph is imported without a previously Qt binding loaded, it decides on its own what binding and version to use. IIRC, that order changed a bit in the past, but right now it's: PyQt6, PySide6, PyQt5, PySide2; it tries to import that in that order, as soon as the first import is successful, it will use that binding. For obvious reasons, you cannot use different Qt versions, but that's also true for different bindings: while they practically do the same thing, PySide and PyQt are not compatible, and attempting to mix ->

Comment: -> them results in unexpected and misleading errors (exactly like yours), since the class names are the same. The generic convention is that the order of imports should not change their behavior or that of the program, but that cannot obviously be true for modules that rely on other libraries and try to use them even in standalone mode (something pyqtgraph is capable of). So, you should always import first the base library those module may use; eventually use the env variable `PYQTGRAPH_QT_LIB` with its value set with the binding name (eg. `PYQTGRAPH_QT_LIB="PyQt5" ...` or using `os.environ`).

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify the stretch.
Can you run [this example?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqtgraph-creating-graph-item/)
Also I've normally used pyqt.PlotWidget for general graphing with no problems.

Comment: Obviously this is a MWE and in my actual usage, I add a number of plots to the GraphicsLayoutWidget, so I think it is warranted. Yet, on the machine in question, if I were to replace the x declaration above with x = pg.PlotWidget() and try to add it, the code errors out and returns the same error.